Typescript Function Overload Parameters
I am trying to create a function overload for an API call with a delete method. Here's what I have so far:
type ApiCore = { endpoint: string; key: string };

export type ApiParams = {
  routeParam?: string;
  queryParams?: FormatQueryParams;
};

function deleteApi(
  core: ApiCore
): (ids: string[], params?: ApiParams) => Promise<string[]>;
function deleteApi<Schema>(
  core: ApiCore
): (params: ApiParams, param2?: ApiParams) => Promise<Schema & BaseSchema>;
function deleteApi<Schema>({
  endpoint,
  key,
}: ApiCore): (
  param1: string[] | ApiParams,
  param2?: ApiParams
) => Promise<(Schema & BaseSchema) | string[]> {
  return async function (param1, param2 = {}) {
    if (Array.isArray(param1)) {
      const { queryParams, routeParam } = param2;

      const { data } = await api.delete(
        `${endpoint}${routeParam ? `/${routeParam}` : ''}${formatQueryParams(
          queryParams
        )}`,
        { data: { [key]: param1 } }
      );

      return data.result || data.data;
    }

    const { queryParams, routeParam } = param1;
    const { data } = await api.delete(
      `${endpoint}${routeParam ? `/${routeParam}` : ''}${formatQueryParams(
        queryParams
      )}`
    );

    return data.result || data.data;
  };
}

The function is being curried because it will be passed to a factory function that creates other requests. As you can see, the inner asynchronous function requires at least one argument, which can either be string[] or ApiParams object. The problem is that whenever I would pass in an array of strings, Typescript complains that Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'ApiParams' such as in this implementation:
const service = (endpoint: string, key: string) => ({
  delete: (param1: string[] | ApiParams, param2?: ApiParams) => 
    deleteApi({ endpoint, key })(param1, param2)
    //                           ^Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'ApiParams'
})


I'm confused, shouldn't it accept it? Thank you.

• Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] where the only issues we see when looking at it in our own IDEs are the issues you're having trouble with. That means any undeclared types or values should be declared or removed (what's BaseSchema? what's FormatQueryParams? what's api? etc etc).  Also, you are overloading the wrong thing; it should be the returned function that's overloaded, not the original one.  So a [mre] here might look like this playground link. Could you please edit the code accordingly and then we can address the issue?

(see prev comment) • Once you edit, then the issue is it's a missing feature of TS, requested at ms/TS#14107; for now if you want a union of call signatures then you have to make it yourself, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcals sorry for the missing types, I thought they were irrelevant enough and can just be supplemented with anything really. Yes, this playground that you made accurately reflects the problem. Function overloading is a new concept for me, so I used ChatGPT to teach me and I tried to implement my own.

@jcalz thank you for your time, the answer below has successfully address my question.

I guess you are overcomplicating, just return an overloaded function and use it directly:
Playground
type ApiCore = { endpoint: string; key: string };
type FormatQueryParams = {};
type BaseSchema = {};

export type ApiParams = {
  routeParam?: string;
  queryParams?: FormatQueryParams;
};

function deleteApi({  endpoint,  key,}: ApiCore)
 {
  function out(ids: string[], params?: ApiParams): Promise<string[]>;
  function out(params: ApiParams, params2?: ApiParams): Promise<BaseSchema>
  async function out(param1: string[] | ApiParams, param2: ApiParams = {}){
    return 1 as any;
  }
  return out;
}

const service = (endpoint: string, key: string) => ({
  delete: deleteApi({ endpoint, key })
});

const s = service('','');

s.delete([]).then(r =>{
  r; // string[]
});

